# How to change "Select Options" Button redirect to Single Product Page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have displayed products in a carousel and when hovering on the products it's showing "Select Options" for the variation based products and "Add to Cart" for simple products.

Screenshot - https://paste.pics/FDRMO

Here is the screenshot after hitting Select Options:
https://paste.pics/FDRN8

Now the problem is when I click on "Select Options" it's opening a new window with the products variations which I don't want it to do, Instead I want it to redirect the user to the single product page on click, how can I do that the template is quick view and the code is mentioned below:

```
<div class="product-element-top">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" class="product-image-link">
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woodmart_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>
</a>
<?php woodmart_hover_image(); ?>
<div class="wd-buttons wd-pos-r-t<?php echo woodmart_get_old_classes( ' woodmart-buttons' ); ?>">
    <?php woodmart_enqueue_js_script( 'btns-tooltip' ); ?>
    <?php woodmart_add_to_compare_loop_btn(); ?>
    <?php woodmart_quick_view_btn( get_the_ID() ); ?>
    <?php do_action( 'woodmart_product_action_buttons' ); ?>
</div>

<div class="wd-add-btn wd-add-btn-replace<?php echo woodmart_get_old_classes( ' woodmart-add-btn' ); ?>">
    <?php if ( woodmart_loop_prop( 'product_quantity' ) ): ?>
        <?php woodmart_product_quantity( $product ); ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
</div>
<?php woodmart_quick_shop_wrapper(); ?>
```